# How to set a box on bottom of a box?

Tags: jquery, css

How do I have to set css position to animate box(in) that is in the box(out) which is not equal to box(in) height, from down to up.

What I am trying with animating is:

```
$('#box-out').hover(function(){
    $('#box-in').animate({height: '400px'},2000);
});
```

It expands downwards as hover right? I just want it to expand upwards. To be able to do that I have to set push it on bottom of box(out).

How do I do that?
Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/DxEMT/

Comment: try setting a top margin which is (say) 200 to begin with and animates to 0. Set the number to whatever your change in height is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DxEMT/1/

Comment: Yes!!! just like that!

Comment: OK. Arun's answer is more elegant. I'd suggest going with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#box-out{
    width:300px; 
    height:400px; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    position: relative;
} 
#box-in{
    width:300px; 
    height:100px; 
    background:red; 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QV5cA/)

Comment: To explain this for the OP: This works because it positions the inner div at the bottom of the outer div (`position:absolute;bottom:0`), meaning the height is now measured up instead of down. It also needs the `position:relative` on the outer div, otherwise the inner div would be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yea.. I had tried position:absolute en bottom: 0 but didn't think that I had to give relative position to box(out).. thnx for the answer!

Comment: Just..for the second fiddle I would rather use .stop().animate!

Answer (score 2):

Absolute position #box-in inside #box-out with bottom: 0; and give #box-out `position-relative`
That will do the trick.

```
#box-out{
   width:300px; 
   height:400px; 
   border:1px solid black; 
   position: relative;
} 
#box-in{
   float:left; 
   width:300px; 
   height:100px; 
   background:red; 
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

The rest is same as your existing code.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DxEMT/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box-out').hover(function(){
    $('#box-in').animate({
        height: '-400px'
    },2000);


});
```

Make it expand upwards by inverting the height?

Answer (score 0):

try position absolute .. [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxEMT/4/)

```
#box-out
{
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
} 
#box-in
{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```